# what does python really do when it starts to run?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I learned that the SyntaxError is the only error that can not be caught.
for example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "main running"  
    try:
        for i in range(3):
    except SyntaxError,e:
        print "error caught"
    finally:
        print "i am here"
```

well, I expect print "main running" could be displayed, well it doesn't
so does python check all the syntax before it runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to detect `SyntaxError` at runtime because invalid syntax compromises the validity of the whole module, not only of the specific line where the author perceives to have made a mistake. Since the interpreter doesn't understand the author's intentions, the only thing it can do after failing to read the source is raise the error.

As Martin Pieters answered, the failure occurs at the compilation step at which Python reads the whole module and compiles it to memory before running it. However, even without a separate compilation step, the underlying problem with catching inline syntax errors at run-time would remain.

To catch syntax errors at run-time within the same module, one must isolate the erroneous code from the surrounding code. This can be done using the `exec` statement or the `eval` function:

```
>>> try:
...     exec """
... this doesn't work  
... """
... except SyntaxError:
...     print "fail"
... 
fail
```

To catch syntax errors in imported modules, simply put the `try`/`except` around the `import` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Python *compiles* the code to bytecode first. If that fails, a `SyntaxError` is raised, indicating a failure to compile.

As such you cannot catch a `SyntaxError` exception from within the module that *has* a syntax error itself. Since Python compiles files as needed, you *can* catch `SyntaxError` exceptions for modules you import.

The following prints `Failed to import test`:

*test.py*

```
print,
```

*catchsyntaxerror.py*

```
try:
    import test
except SyntaxError:
    print 'Failed to import test'
```

then run `python catchsyntaxerror.py`.

Comment: you mean that it compiles to the .pyc ?

Comment: @cui: The `.pyc` file is the byte code cache, storing the result of the compilation, yes.

Comment: @cui If you just run a script (as opposed to importing a module), Python will compile the script into memory.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters i tried ,it is really as you said. it seems that python only tried to find the obvious syntax from the main.py,it check the imported files SyntaxError at run time